# in Rust when you would type function::<type>()?

Tags: types, rust, compilation

in Rocket documentation I found this construction

```
request.guard::<&State<MyConfig>>().await
```

I understand await and `&` but this `func::<type>()` part is completely different from what I have seen in other mainstream languages `func()` like C++, C#, Java, python...
probably best answer would be to point me to the right reading material about it because it's not framework specific

Comment: [Generics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-01-syntax.html). More precisely you call a function this way when the compiler can't directly infer the type. Now, please, this question is much too wide.

Comment: Not so different from C++ - if you define a function as `template<typename T> func() { ... }`, you can call it as `func<int>()`. This is the same thing, except the type is `&State<MyConfig>`. It explicitly specifies the type for the generic function, presumably because the type could not be inferred  from function arguments (as the function accepts no arguments). The `::<...>` operator is sometimes referred to as [the turbofish](https://techblog.tonsser.com/posts/what-is-rusts-turbofish).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called the turbofish, and is used for generics - and sometimes used when the Rust compiler cannot infer the type of some variable, for specifying the concrete type of that variable.

See [non-operator symbols on the Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-02-operators.html#non-operator-symbols) for more information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a good answer. Adding a link to the docs (https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-02-operators.html#non-operator-symbols) would bring it up to a _great_ answer.